# Google caching issue

Tags: javascript, caching, googlebot

I have a situation. I introduced a website redirection with javascript for every user that doesn't support a specific browser. 
I was sure that Google cache will always put homepage as the cached page. But however, when I look at Google cache page I see a redirection page. As far as I know, Googlebot ignores javascript on pages so I tested it with javascript turned off and using Googlebot user agent and I got homepage displayed.

Here is the code of javascript redirection:

```
var 
                ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
                uaVersion = 0,
                isIE = !isOpera && (ua.indexOf("msie") >= 0),
                isFirefox = !!isGecko && (ua.indexOf("firefox/") >= 0),
                isChrome = !!isWebKit && (ua.indexOf("chrome/") >= 0),
                isSafari = (ua.indexOf("safari") >= 0),
                isValid = false,
                userLang = (navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language).split("-")[0].toLowerCase();

            if (isIE)
                uaVersion = parseFloat(ua.match(/msie (\d+\.\d+)/)[1]);

            if (isFirefox)
                uaVersion = parseFloat(ua.match(/ firefox\/(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]);

            if (isSafari)
                uaVersion = parseFloat(ua.match(/ safari\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);

            if (isChrome)
                uaVersion = parseFloat(ua.match(/ chrome\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);

         if (!isIE && !isFirefox && !isSafari && !isChrome)
             isValid = true;
         else 
                isValid = (isIE && (uaVersion >= 8)) || (isFirefox && (uaVersion >= 16)) || (isSafari && (uaVersion >= 5)) || (isChrome && (uaVersion >= 11));

            if (!isValid)
                window.location = ["/friendly/browser_", ".html"].join(userLang);
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Google indexing issues will be better handled on Webmasters.SE. Here it is off-topic.

Comment: GoogleBot *does* have JavaScript enabled. And you should not do browsre-detection!

Comment: Ok, but it is requested by client, so it is a MUST right now. Is there any way to let Googlebot pass this check since this don't work even if his useragent string set isValid to be true?

Comment: Another problem with browser-sniffing based redirects is that Google (and other search engines) run crawlers that use standard browser UA strings; if one of those is redirected to something different than the one that announces itself as Googlebot, Google might assume you are trying to use [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking).